# django filter and delete model entries

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am relatively new to django, and I have two models on my DB (`ModelA` and `ModelB`). What I'd like to do is filter `ModelA` values from `ModelB` and delete these values from `ModelB`.

So, for example, `ModelA.values_list` has the following entries:

```
[x,y,z,a,s,d]
```

and `ModelB.values_list` has the following values:

```
[1,2,3,4,x,a,7,d,z]
```

What I'd like to do is operate on `ModelB`, such that it deletes the entry if and only if the value is present in `ModelA`. Also, to add to the problem, len(ModelA) = ~100k size and len(ModelB) = 2million :) So, I'd require something quick.

So, I'd like my `ModelB` to look like:

```
[1,2,3,4,7]
```

i.e all entries from `ModelA` deleted from `ModelB`

How does one achieve such an operation? 
Sorry if the question is daft, but I am looking for a django(ic) way to do this.

Comment: Django is cool and everything, but I would strongly advise you to use some other tool to handle such large amount of data... Django Models does the SQL query the most generic way, if you want some performance, you can code it by yourself (even using django..)

Comment: I agree JRicardo: but, it is an one off operation - and I do not really mind if it takes a bit of time!

Comment: Have you looked into F Expressions? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/queries/#f-expressions

Comment: yea.. I think F expressions are the way to go! Would be happy to accept your answer.